# Citrix Workspace lets me add the store but only when I am not logged in as a specific user

Tags: windows, workspace, citrix, storefront

One of my co-workers has trouble adding the store to his Citrix Workspace App.

When other people are logged in on his PC (i.e. me) it is possible to open Citrix, add the store and login. However when I log back in with his user it is impossible to add the store.

I thought this might be a software related issue so I used the cleanup tool, I rebooted his PC and then I installed the latest version with the /forceinstall parameter so that it cleans up all previous installations and any files that de old Receiver Cleanup tool might have missed.

That didn't help so I checked the DNS to see if the storename was properly translated and it was.

So it is not related to the installation or the network. I made him log in on another PC and try it there and it works so it hasn't got anything to do with rights on user-level.

I've been comparing all files related between my AppData and his AppData to try and spot any anomalies but so far I haven't found anything. The next step is to rename his user folder to "USERNAME.old" and make him start over with a clean slate or just completely re-image his PC... I would rather avoid this because it is pretty overkill for a Citrix problem.

Has anyone experienced this before or am I missing something?

Thanks!